# How can I print from vim using the native KDE print dialogue?

Tags: linux, printing

I'm using `vim` from a terminal emulator, and I'd like to be able to print using KDE's native print dialogue. This would let me select options such as printer, collating, number of copies and pages per piece of paper.

(There is an older tip [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Printing_using_kprinter) explaining how to link vim with `kprinter`, but this does not work, and I suspect `kprinter` has been deprecated.)

I know that I can "print" to a postscript file with `:ha > foo.ps` (or `:hardcopy`), then open this up with a GUI viewer, such as `okular`, but is there a way to get directly to the print dialogue from `vim`? (Also, I assume it's impossible, but can I open up a print preview window too?)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I don't totally understand my [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Printing_using_kprinter) above, but I thought perhaps that it was piping the "hardcopy" postscript file to KDE's print interface. Hence, I thought that my question wasn't so much about Vim being compatible with KDE, but more about finding the right KDE component to receive the hardcopy.

Comment: kprinter was removed from the KDE4 source, and someone published a clone: https://github.com/credativ/kprinter4

Comment: @muru Yes, I think that's the same one that John O'M. mentioned in his [answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2435/1278) below.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that answer. I came across this in the review queue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The loss of kprinter in the move to kde4 was one of the reasons I stuck with kde3 for as long as I could.

After some searching, I found this "3rd party" replacement: http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/KPrinter4?content=163537, https://github.com/credativ/kprinter4.

It looks like you have to compile it yourself (Its not included in distros since it isn't core kde). The result works like the old one that came with kde3, but in the kde4 environment. It is used the same way, except the executable is called kprinter4.

Note: Some non-KDE alternatives are presented at the bottom.

I tried following the instructions at the vimwiki link you posted to use it, but I found those difficult to follow (too many escaped characters), so I based my vimrc on the function method found in `:help pexpr-option`

## Building the executable

This bit isn't about Vim, but is a prereq to the solution. I'm writing this with limited assumptions about your (or whoever else finds this answer useful) knowledge of building software.

1. Download the "latest" source to kprinter4 from the link above. I used http://kde-apps.org/content/download.php?content=163537&id=1&tan=32050597
2. Extract into some directory: `tar xf 163537-kprinter4-12.tar.xz` (filename may be different for a newer version)
3. Cd into the source directory: `cd kprinter4-12` (directory may be different in a newer version)
4. Create a build directory and change into it: `mkdir build && cd build`
5. Run cmake. I used the options given at the kde-apps page, but changed the INSTALL_PREFIX such that I don't need to be administrator to install (but the install is only for me):

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/john/opt/kprinter4 ..
   ```

   The trailing `..` is important. The INSTALL_PREFIX can be whatever you want, but it will be used in your vimrc (see below). You'll at least want to replace my username with your own.

   If the command fails, it will probably tell you that you are missing libraries (for me it was missing LIBSPECTRE). Install whatever is missing and loop until cmake is successful. (e.g. in my case: `apt-get install libspectre-dev`) Depending on your distro and setup, different commands and package names may be needed.
6. Run make: `make`
7. Install: `make install`

## Configure Vim

I'm using the install path  from my sample isntructions above (which include my home directory). Change the paths as appropriate for your system (e.g. replacing my username with yours, or whatever you did for the INSTALL_PREFIX in the above section)

In my vimrc:

```
function PrintFile(fname)
   call system("/home/john/opt/kprinter4/bin/kprinter4 " . a:fname)
   call delete(a:fname)
   return v:shell_error
endfunction
set printexpr=PrintFile(v:fname_in)
```

This creates a function that calls your newly built `kprinter4` program and then cleans up the file whenever you run :hardcopy.

After that, run `:hardcopy` on a document and get a pretty printer selector:

[image: Screenshot of kprinter4 on top of a vim session that had just run :hardcopy]

## Non-KDE Alternatives

Some Linux distributions provide `gpr` and/or `gtklp` (thanks @derobert and @Sparhawk for pointing out and testing these in the comments/chat)

### gpr

Example for using gpr (presently available on Ubuntu but not Arch). Note that this errors on my system due to a missing PPD file or something. Your mileage may vary.

```
function PrintFile(fname)
   call system("gpr " . a:fname)
   call delete(a:fname)
   return v:shell_error
endfunction
set printexpr=PrintFile(v:fname_in)
```

[image: Screenshot of gpr after :hardcopy]

### gtklp

Example for using gtklp (Available on both Ubuntu and Arch)

```
function PrintFile(fname)
   call system("gtklp " . a:fname)
   call delete(a:fname)
   return v:shell_error
endfunction
set printexpr=PrintFile(v:fname_in)
```

[image: Screenshot of gtklp after :hardcopy]

### Alternative gtklp

At least one person has had an issue where gtklp on Arch Linux doesn't accept files specified on the command line. Below is an alternative method that works in that case (or in any case) that passes the contents of the file instead.

```
function PrintFile(fname)
   call system("cat " . a:fname . " | gtklp")
   call delete(a:fname)
   return v:shell_error
endfunction
set printexpr=PrintFile(v:fname_in)
```

[image: Screenshot of gtklp after :hardcopy but with a pipe]

Note that with this method, gtklp doesn't even have a files tab displayed, but it does in fact print the document when `print` is selected.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable solution (+1), but is there no solution with the core (or semi-core) KDE packages? I read that [kprinter](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/kprinter-available-for-kde-4/) has been replaced by a qt/kde-specific program, but presumably my gtk apps use another frontend.

Comment: I think the answer is that there isn't a native way. What I had read was that the kprinter program was replaced by the built-in qt printer dialog (i.e. a function call that can be made from within a program that uses qt). That transition resulted in the removal of the stand-alone program `kprinter`. There is some info and discussion at the following link (which then links to what I posted in the answer) https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/kprinter-available-for-kde-4/

Comment: We linked to the same thing! :) Okay, I'll leave the question up for a little while anyway, and I'll accept your answer if I don't hear anything better.

Comment: @Sparhawk Hah, indeed. I missed the link when I first read your comment and posted mine. Anyway, I've just added build and vimrc instructions to make my answer more complete (and less of a link-only answer). That still doesn't help you find a built-in solution, but hopefully it helps others looking for this.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the instructions; they are so clear! I'm using Arch, so I'd do it via a PKGBUILD, which has it's own… peculiarities, but your instructions look very helpful. BTW, are you using Ubuntu? Do you know if there's a way to pipe hardcopy to its native print dialogue? If so, I wonder if I could co-opt a different DE's print frontend… (which I was implying with my first comment).

Comment: @Sparhawk As you guess, I am running Ubuntu 14.04 at the moment. I don't have my Arch machine handy. Any DE with a standalone print front-end program would work similar to kprinter/kprinter4. I couldn't find a standalone "native" dialog for Ubuntu. I did find a package for Ubuntu called `gpr` which is a gnome-ish print dialog like kprinter that is used similarly. Unfortunately, it gives me a PPD error every time I try to use it. Worse, it doesn't seem available for Arch (I don't see it listed at https://www.archlinux.org/packages/).

Comment: Ah ok. I thought perhaps the Gnome, XFCE or LXDE printer frontends might be options. And I still don't know what non-Qt apps use in KDE.

Comment: @Sparhawk you could use gtklp, there are other printer frontends. But they have a different interface (at least slightly) than the KDE one.

Comment: @derobert Thanks, that seems like an acceptable answer. However, do you specifically know how to pipe to it from `vim`?

Comment: @Sparhawk following the above answer, replace the path to kprinter4 with `gtklp`, e.g: `call system("gtklp " . a:fname)`. This will use gtklp as the print handler.

Comment: @derobert and JohnO'M. I don't think gtklp works here. I don't think it's passing the files correctly. http://i.imgur.com/DSWRYBx.png

Comment: @Sparhawk that's odd. Mine shows an item like `/tmp/vtPmLMz/10` in the "Files to print" list. Can you show us what your current settings for this in your vimrc are (either updating the question, via pastebin, or a screenshot of it in another comment)?

Comment: I created a [minimal vimrc](http://pastebin.com/gqX9rdaf), which still exhibits this behaviour. I also have a bunch of plugins that I unloaded, launching vim with `vim -u ~/.vimrc foo`.

Comment: @Sparhawk just tried it with your vimrc, and it still works for me. What happens if you run gtklp from the commandline? (e.g. as `gtklp somefakefile`). Does it show the arguments in the file list, or leave the file list empty still?

Comment: Ha! Odd… The file list is still empty. I tried both a text file and a postscript file. Perhaps I'm missing a dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21836/discussion-between-john-om-and-sparhawk).

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness: If `kprinter4` doesn't work, you can also make a parallel installation of (relevant components of) Trinity KDE (TDE) desktop, which is available in some distros such as Debian or Arch. Then you can use good old `kprinter` instead of `kprinter4`:

```
set popt=duplex:off 
set printexpr=PrintFile(v:fname_in)
function PrintFile(fname)
  call system("/opt/trinity/bin/kprinter " . a:fname)
  call delete(a:fname)
  return v:shell_error
endfunc
```

Answer (score 0):

vim's `:ha` wasn't printing UTF-8 characters, and I wanted an built-in preview anyway. In the end, I just decided to convert to a pdf and open that instead.

```
command Printpreview w! /tmp/vim_print.txt | call system("unoconv /tmp/vim_print.txt && xdg-open /tmp/vim_print.pdf")
```